# Python: Is there any way to get a list of IPs connected to a network

Tags: networking, python, wifi

Is there any way to get a list of IPs connected to a network? I'm trying to build lots of networking tools so.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-255
```

where `192.168.1` must be substituted with your local network address known from
 `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though RFC 1122 requires any host on the network has to process an echo-request and issue an echo-reply in return it's well known that 'paranoid' people think of ping as an security risk and therefore decline to answer echo-request. So obviously no answer is no definite proof of any given host not being online.

However maybe you want to investigate `nmap` and the python libs that make use of it.

Comment: Hope it helps..